# What are cons to write and manage CSS in notepad?

Tags: css

What are cons to write and manage CSS in notepad? in compare to any css IDE?

specially in team environment? How much it will effect to project timeline if we are forced to use notepad.

should we always use an IDE for CSS?

Comment: For me, None! NotePad2 and I'm happy! Works great! But when using Visual Studio 2010 and web-development I tend to use VS built-in Texteditor.

Comment: Notepad2 is *very* different to Notepad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No Auto-intelligence
2. Need to remember each keyword and syntax
3. No Formatting and alignment
4. No Rapid Development
5. No Syntax Highlighter
6. No CSS Checker and Validator
7. No CSS Beautifier
8. No Code collapse functionality

Answer (score 0):

I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) for editing my CSS and one of the things it does better than Notepad is syntax highlighting and occassionally formatting and indentation.

Syntax highlighting isn't that important for CSS but at least having an editor with that does cut down on typo errors.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only cons:

- you're not able to automatically format your CSS code
  you will need to do indentation yourself
- prone to errors
  nobody writes perfect codes, and without an IDE, chances is there will be errors here and there
- No inline code hinting
  you probably need to know what to type, for there are no hinting what values are able to be entered for that property.
- no syntax highlighting
  stop straining your eyes!

But for me, time is precious. I'll rather open CSS files and edit them in Notepad, rather than spending some time opening, saving code and closing an IDE just to edit few lines of CSS code.